# Foreign key in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm using Rails 4 and SQLite. I'm trying to add foreing keys to my `indicators` table. Please see my code below

```
class Indicator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :objetive
  belongs_to :responsible, class_name: "Person"

end
```

The migration script:

```
class AddFksToIndicator < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_reference :indicators, :objective, index: true
      add_reference :indicators, :responsible, index: true
  end
end
```

when run the migration all is ok, so I tried in console:

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > i = Indicator.new
 => #<Indicator id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, objective_id: nil, responsible_id: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > i.objective_id = 0
2.0.0p247 :003 > i.save
```

To my surprise, the indicator was saved and there is no `obective` with id = 0.

Finally, I checked the indicators table schema and I get:

```
CREATE TABLE "indicators" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "objective_id" integer, "responsible_id" integer);
CREATE INDEX "index_indicators_on_objective_id" ON "indicators" ("objective_id");
CREATE INDEX "index_indicators_on_responsible_id" ON "indicators" ("responsible_id");
```

Why there is no foreign key constraint on `objective_id` and `responsible_id`?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SQLite *does* support foreign keys, so someone who is ambitious and tied to using SQLite could improve the adaptor to support this too.  But it's much easier to just switch to using Postgres in development.  That will give you so many other benefits, so it's really a no-brainer.  SQLite is awesome [_for what it was built for_](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), but Rails development is ***not*** its ideal use case.  Running Postgres is not difficult at all, and it makes sense to have the same DB in development that you use in production.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Ruby on Rails 4.2 Release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html), only the mysql, mysql2 and postgresql adapters support foreign keys.

Unfortunately, the sqlite3 adapter does not.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `add_reference`, you'd need to add `foreign_key: true` to to get foreign key support with that call. For example:

`add_reference :indicators, :objective, index: true, foreign_key: true`

The default is `foreign_key: false`, as mentioned in the docs [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

Since you've already created your migration without a foreign key, you'll need to create another migration with a call to `add_foreign_key`.

For example:

```
def change
   # add_foreign_key(from_table, to_table)
   add_foreign_key :indicators, :objectives
end
```

Here's the [documentation for `add_foreign_key`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key).

Hope this helps.